# Redirect and replace the last character of the url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I've some urls ending with question mark (e.g. www.example.com/cars?).

This creates a problem of duplicate content because:

`www.example.com/cars?`

`www.example.com/cars`

Furthermore, I'ld like replace ? with / (again for seo purpose, because is a url of a category) so to obtain something like:

`www.example.com/cars/`

I tried something like:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?\s
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

(sorry I can't test here)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule to remove trailing `?` from your URLs:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+[^?]*\?\s
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [NE,R=301,L]
```